# How to create a java class with dynamic number of variables

Tags: java

I want to create a java class with dynamic number of variables. Those dynamic variables will be read from a config file.

Example: I have a properties file like,

```
{
 "data": "int",
 "name": "string",
 "addr": "string",
 "age" : "int"
}
```

In some cases, new variables can be there or few variables are missing from above config.

I want to create a java with variables mentioned in above properties file. Is it possible in java to create such class and if yes then can someone provide sample code for that?

Comment: You can use a `Map`

Comment: If those variables can be any number and with any names, the `Map` or `Properties` is the way to go. If there is a pattern in them, you may consider subclasses: each subclass can add any number of variables to those inherited from the superclass. It’s not really dynamic, though.

Answer (score 1):

Define a  `Map<String, String>`  that you can access by the key,

but why?

at the end all those "variables" will be the same type... -> String...

the same principe is done in config or property files....

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do a bit more research on java classes. There is no java class that has a dynamic "number" of variables. But you can give a class attributes, but require only some are set, for example.

```
class DataFile {

    int data;
    String name;
    String addr;
    int age;
}
```

And then you can create setters and getters for each field.

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

That way you can instantiate a member of the class and set the data you have.

```
DataFile d = new DataFile();
d.setName("John");
```

Remember that any class methods like setName and getName have to be inside the { } that define the class to which they belong. They aren't here just to separate them visually.

Answer (score 0):

All of that already exists. It is called "Properties" in Java, too.

So, simply read about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)!

In other words: you could/should use [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html); and there is full support for reading that information from files; or writing to.

The Java property file format does not match your current file format; but well, when you are doing "true" Java, then the most "off the shelf" solution are Java properties; so so you could consider to change your file format.

And to give the actual answer: Java does not support a dynamic number of fields. That is what Maps are used for; and the Property class is exactly that - some sort of Map with additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
public class Model {
  Map model;

  public Model(String json) {
    model = new Gson().fromJson(jsonModel, Map.class);
  }

  public Object getValue(String key) {
    return model.get(key);
  }
}
```

But you'd rather want your model to hold data for values, leaving the type inference of the fields to Java.